# How to find the stitch (seam) position between two images with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I find many examples of passing a list of images, and returning a stitched image, but not much information about *how* these images have beeen stitched together.

In a project, we have a camera fixed still, pointing down, and coveyers pass underneath. The program detects objects and start recording images. However some objects do not enter completely in the image, so we need to capture multiple images and stich then together, but we need to know the position of the stitched image because there are other sensors synchronized with the captured image, and we need to also synchronize their readings within the stitched image (i.e. we know where the reading is within each single capture, but not if captures are stitched together).

In short, given a list of images, how can we find the coordinates of each images relative to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Basically while stiching correspondence between two (or more) images are setup. This is done with some constant key points. After finding those key points the images are warped or transformed & put together, i.e. stitched.
Now those key points could be set/ noted as per a global coordinate system (containing all images). Then one can get the position after stitching too.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the steps are similar to panaroma stitching. You can follow this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/) for your problem.

Basically, one/some image(s) will be your reference image(s), and you will find the transformation between it and the other ones. These transformations will be your 4*3 homography matrices. Any point in an image can be transformed into another image's coordinate system using these matrices [homography](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography). So, you can overcome the occlusion issue that you are trying to solve. [Another source for homography](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html).